# Django custom user admin login session is not created

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have used a custom user model as auth user model. But while trying to login as admin in the Django admin site. The user is getting authenticated and added to the request.user but session is not created and when it redirects I guess the request.user is lost.
Logs

```
[16/Dec/2021 14:13:24] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[16/Dec/2021 14:13:24] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[16/Dec/2021 14:13:24] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2212
```

Users.py - The custom User model which extends the abstract base user

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin, UserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# from models.legacy import Orders, Packages, Payouts


class CustomAbstractBaseUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        """
        Return a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct. Handles
        hashing formats behind the scenes.
        """
        def setter(raw_password):
            self.set_password(raw_password)
            # Password hash upgrades shouldn't be considered password changes.
            self._password = None
            # self.save(update_fields=["password"])
        return check_password(raw_password, 'bcrypt$' + self.password, setter)


class Accounts(CustomAbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'emailid'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'fullname']

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'accounts'

    created = models.DateTimeField()
    # Field name made lowercase.
    accountid = models.IntegerField(db_column='accountId', primary_key=True)
    # Field name made lowercase.
    isaffiliate = models.IntegerField(db_column='isAffiliate')
    blocked = models.IntegerField()
    amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Settings.py - The simple jwt is working perfectly fine but it needs not to store the session so there is no problem with that but admin user login is the only thing I am struggling with.

```
"""
Django settings for lms project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-mwvscxa&@@ezj-55rl7mle-f$_txcxw$*husf=c0yt7qgmkgs4'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.5', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'growpartner.Accounts'

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'growpartner',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lms.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lms.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'legacy_growpartner',
        'USER': os.getenv('USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('PASS'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('HOST'),
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
]

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'account_id',
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ],
    # 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    # 'PAGE_SIZE': 30
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

UPDATE: After more debugging I found that it is logging in session is created and the request is done more than once so the cookie is again deleted and thus not able to login.

Comment: Can you add the error to your question and your custom user model/manager?

Comment: @IainShelvington There is actually no error

Comment: What do you mean session is not created ? Does your user get logout ?

Comment: What does "it shows EmptyManager object" mean if it's not an error, where is this shown?

Comment: @GaëtanGR the table django_session remains empty if I try the same in another project without the custom user model a session entry is added to the table

Comment: @IainShelvington Sorry that is by default when you access login page found out while I was debugging.

Comment: @MuhammadUzair please add your custom user model and manager to the question

Comment: Also, please add your settings.py if you've correctly changed the value for AUTH_USER_MODEL to your custom model

Comment: @IainShelvington I have added users.py

Comment: @JervenClark I have added the settings.py and yes I am using AUTH_USER_MODEL